# converting a line in matlab to python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, image-processing

I'm trying to convert MATLAB code to Python and I'm stuck at this line:

I have a 3 dimensional image. When I run `image.shape`, I get `(455L,621L,3L)`
which means 455 rows, 621 columns and 3 color channels.

What I do in MATLAB is `image(:,:,2:3)` which means get all the rows, get all the columns and take channels 2 and 3.

When I try to convert to Python/numpy, I do this which is wrong:

```
img2a = img2[0:img2.shape[0]][0:img2.shape[1]][1:2]
```

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: You've been here for a few days, I've seen your questions. You very rarely seem to give feedback to commenters and answerers, unless something goes wrong. So I'd like to inform you that if you found a given answer satisfactory to your question, please consider marking it as accepted by clicking the check-mark to the left of the answer. If something's missing, don't hesitate to comment on the answers: you'll always be able to comment on answers to your questions. Both answerers and you benefit from a solved question: our efforts get paid in reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab and Numpy are somewhat similar for indexing and slicing. In this case, they're almost identical: `image[:,:,1:3]` should work in Numpy. The major difference here is the zero start vs the one start to indexes.

It seems, though, that you might benefit from reading up on [indexing in Numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

In most cases, 0 and the end of an axis can both be implied by just leaving them out (eg `x[:5]` gets 0 through 4, while `x[4:]` gets 4 through the end of the axis), so there's no need to include 0 or get shape info.